# Dúvida sobre remoção de nós - Estrutura de dados

Tags: c, lista-encadeada, codeblocks

ATUALIZAÇÃO DA PERGUNTA: tenho uma dúvida persistente na função remover_nodos que vou tentar apresentar de forma clara e coerente: por que o código 1 não funciona e entra em loop infinito mas o código 2 funciona? Quero saber se alguém conseguiu entender a lógica por trás e se pudesse me explicar como funciona agradeceria bastante. Abaixo seguem os códigos com a devida identificação de cada um.

**Código 1 da função remover_nodos que não funciona e entra em loop:**

```
struct Nodo *remover_nodos(struct Nodo *cabeca, int tamanho, int qtd_para_remover)
{
    struct Nodo *aux = cabeca, *paux;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover); i++)
    {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }

    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        free(aux);
        aux = paux;
    }

    return cabeca;
};
```

**Código 2 da função remover_nodos que funciona:**

```
struct Nodo *remover_nodos(struct Nodo *cabeca, int tamanho, int qtd_para_remover)
{
    struct Nodo *aux = cabeca, *paux;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover - 1); i++)
    {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }

    while(aux->proximo != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        aux->proximo = paux->proximo;
        free(paux);
    }
    return cabeca;
};
```

**Código geral do programa com o código 2 na função remover_nodos:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Nodo
{
    int informacao;
    struct Nodo *proximo;
};

struct Nodo *criar_lista(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

struct Nodo *insercao_nodos(int valor, struct Nodo *cabeca)
{
    struct Nodo *novo = (struct Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
    novo->informacao = valor;
    novo->proximo = cabeca;
    return novo;
};

void imprimir_valores(struct Nodo *cabeca)
{
    struct Nodo *aux;

    for(aux = cabeca; aux != NULL; aux = aux->proximo)
    {
        printf("%d\t", aux->informacao);
    }
}

struct Nodo *remover_nodos(struct Nodo *cabeca, int tamanho, int qtd_para_remover)
{
    struct Nodo *aux = cabeca, *paux;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover); i++)
    {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }

    while(aux->proximo != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        aux->proximo = paux->proximo;
        free(paux);
    }
    return cabeca;
};

int main()
{
    struct Nodo *cabeca;
    int tam = 0;
    int qtd_remover = 0;
    cabeca = criar_lista();
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(4, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(1, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(3, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(2, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(5, cabeca);
    tam++;
    printf("VALORES INSERIDOS\n");
    imprimir_valores(cabeca);
    printf("\nREMOCAO DE NODOS\n");
    printf("Nodos inseridos: %d", tam);
    printf("\nNodos a remover: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtd_remover);
    while(qtd_remover > tam)
    {
        printf("Quantidade de nodos a remover e maior que a quantidade de nodos existentes! Digite novamente: ");
        scanf("%d", &qtd_remover);
    }
    cabeca = remover_nodos(cabeca, tam, qtd_remover);
    imprimir_valores(cabeca);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Você deveria definir a variável tam antes de incrementar, porque ele pode ser qualquer valor antes de usar...

Comment: Isso mostra o valor de tam sem ser definido: https://onlinegdb.com/lWoeoluT_

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O erro está na função de remoção de nodes nesse trecho da comparação condicional do for  "i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover)" por causa da atribuição de aux que depois é atribuida pelo próximo valor no primeiro loop.

Exemplo:
quantidade = 5
removaqnt = 3

cabeca -> filho1 -> filho2 -> filho3 -> filho4

5 - 3 - 1 = 1

Então ele vai pega o próximo de filho1 e vai remover sucessivamente até o próximo ser null.

**Solução**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Nodo
{
    int informacao;
    struct Nodo *proximo;
};

struct Nodo *criar_lista(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

struct Nodo *insercao_nodos(int valor, struct Nodo *cabeca)
{
    struct Nodo *novo = (struct Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
    novo->informacao = valor;
    novo->proximo = cabeca;
    return novo;
};

void imprimir_valores(struct Nodo *cabeca)
{
    struct Nodo *aux;

    for (aux = cabeca; aux != NULL; aux = aux->proximo)
    {
        printf("%d\t", aux->informacao);
    }
}

struct Nodo *remover_nodos(struct Nodo *cabeca, int tamanho, int qtd_para_remover)
{
    struct Nodo *aux = cabeca, *paux;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover-1); i++)
    {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }

    while (aux->proximo != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        aux->proximo = paux->proximo;
        free(paux);
    }
    return cabeca;
};

int main()
{
    struct Nodo *cabeca;
    int tam = 0;
    int qtd_remover = 0;
    cabeca = criar_lista();
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(4, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(1, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(3, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(2, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(5, cabeca);
    tam++;
    printf("VALORES INSERIDOS\n");
    imprimir_valores(cabeca);
    printf("\nREMOCAO DE NODOS\n");
    printf("Nodos inseridos: %d", tam);
    printf("\nNodos a remover: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &qtd_remover);
    while (qtd_remover > tam)
    {
        printf("Quantidade de nodos a remover e maior que a quantidade de nodos existentes! Digite novamente: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &qtd_remover);
    }
    cabeca = remover_nodos(cabeca, tam, qtd_remover);
    imprimir_valores(cabeca);

    return 0;
}
```

Fonte:

[Por que as variáveis ​​locais não são inicializadas em Java?](https://qastack.com.br/programming/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java#:%7E:text=Se%20o%20programador%2C%20por%20engano%2C%20n%C3%A3o%20inicializou%20uma,vari%C3%A1vel%20para%20evitar%20o%20uso%20de%20valores%20indefinidos.)

Comment: Atribui valor para a variável tamanho, rodei o programa mas ainda está entrando em loop e mostrando diversos números. O que mais daria para fazer para somente excluir os nodos e depois mostrar a lista com os valores atualizados? Não sei se o erro está no método remover_nodos ou no main do código

Comment: Erro que aparecer para mim é na parte de imprimir. Eu peço para remover dois elementos, mas remover somente um e aparecer 4 valores na tela. Visual Studio que estou usando.

Comment: Eu estou usando o CodeBlocks. Atualizei o código ali na pergunta, agora ele exclui sempre 1 a menos do que digitei (quero excluir 3, mas exclui só 2), mas ainda não consegui arrumar para ele excluir a quantidade que digitei

Comment: Veja minha resposta se tiver dúvida pode perguntar.

Comment: Quando na chamada do remover_nodos no main se colocar qtd_remover+1 acaba removendo a quantidade que digitei (cabeca = remover_nodos(cabeca, tam, qtd_remover+1)). Atualização: testei o seu método, mas ao invés de colocar quantidade-1, iniciei o i = 1. Acabou funcionando, vou ver se posso entregar assim, muito obrigada

Comment: @DianaCecília isso seria gambiara e não uma solução. Eu recomendo no for na comparação colocar `i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover-1)`

Comment: Li sua explicação mas ainda não consegui entender o motivo para que `i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover-1)` funcione mas `i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover)` não. Além do mais,  por que a função
 `while (paux != NULL) {
        aux = paux->proximo;
        free(paux);
        paux = aux;
    }`
não funcionou mas 
`while(aux->proximo != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        aux->proximo = paux->proximo;
        free(paux);
    }`
acabou funcionando. Se tiver alguma explicação

Comment: Por exemplo:  `cabeca -> filho1 -> filho2 -> filho3 -> filho4` quantidade = 5 , remocaoqnt = 3. 
Ele vai até o i = 1 `(2 < 5- 3 )` que é o primeiro filho da cabeça e vai remover todos os filhos dele(filho2,filho3,filho4).

Comment: E por que a função `while (paux != NULL) { aux = paux->proximo; free(paux);         paux = aux; }`  (a primeira que estava desenvolvendo junto com meu professor) não funcionou mas a função `while(aux->proximo != NULL) { paux = aux->proximo; aux->proximo = paux->proximo;  free(paux); }` (que só fui jogando valores aleatórios até mudar algo) funcionou?

Comment: Parece que sim.

Comment: Mas você saberia dizer o motivo de uma ter funcionado e a outra não?

Comment: Eu acho que paux não era definido antes e sempre dava null. Isso está correto ou você definia ele antes do while?

Comment: Fui ver nas edições e antes eu atribuía aux->proximo à paux por meio desse while: `while(aux != NULL) { paux = aux->proximo; free(aux); aux = paux; }` e não funcionava. Agora na função `while(aux->proximo != NULL) { paux = aux->proximo; aux->proximo = paux->proximo; free(paux); }` funcionou, mas não consigo entender a lógica por trás